# Retrieve an association in a view from it's id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a product element that has many image_blogs.

I have a image_blog id, and a `@product` containing that image_blog. How can I access it ?

I guess it must look like `@product.image_blogs[:id=>"24"]`. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the unique`id` of the `image_blog`, you don't need `@product` to access it:

```
ImageBlog.find(24)
```

To access, say, the first `image_blog`'s `id` in `@product`:

```
@product.image_blogs.first.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@product.image_blogs.where(id:24) # ruby 1.9 new hash syntax
@product.image_blogs.where(:id => 24) # previous hash syntax
```